# How to transpose a dynamic width table in Alteryx

Tags: alteryx

I have several CSVs with dynamic width and I need to address the last, second last column of every csv to transpose them.
That's how my file looks like:

```
Product | 2015-08-01 | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-01 | 2015-10-01| Comment
ABC     | 13         | 12         | 15         | 14        | Strong
CDE     | 69         | 70         | 71         | 67        | Weak
FGH     | 25         | 25         | 26         | 27        | Stable
```

With every new release of that excel file a date column is added and the comment adjusted for the last date:

```
Product | 2015-08-01 | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-01 | 2015-10-01| 2015-11-01| Comment
ABC     | 13         | 12         | 15         | 14        | 12        | Weak
CDE     | 69         | 70         | 71         | 67        | 67        | Stable
FGH     | 25         | 25         | 26         | 27        | 29        | Strong
```

For now I transpose two different sets, firstly I choose the comment and last date manually and secondly all other prices. Afterwards I join them and all is good. The problem is that I have a big set of files from the last years and I would need to set the last date dynamically to have a transposed table like this:

```
Product | Date | Comment | Price
```

With Product, Date and Price filled for every record and Comment just filled for the last reported date. Is there a way to do this?

related to this post:
[How to resolve duplicate column names in excel file with Alteryx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161337/how-to-resolve-duplicate-column-names-in-excel-file-with-alteryx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you want to do is to split that Comment column into it's on data stream?

After the transpose, you can crosstab into a form that contains the products as headers and the dates and comments as individual rows.  Then a filter can pull the comment row out.  A sort on the Name field would also let you grab the last row in that dataset to know which one was the last date.

For the crosstab:
  - Grouping Fields: Name
  - Header Field: Product
  - Data Field: Value

Methodologies: Concatenate

Comment: That seems unnecessarily complicated but it does the job! thanks again!